# how to iterate all items from Document Library in SPD workflow?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I want to iterate through all Document library item using Looping in SPD workflow but whatever thing I have tried that is not showing any result the i have puted the result related variables in Log but these are empty my Workflow is as per bellow snapp
[image]
when I'm checking the History there it is showing reslut as per bellow snapp
[image]

Comment: How are you triggering the workflow ?